# How do publishers expect authors to use social media to promote their books?

Tags: publishing, marketing, social-media, first-time-author

I am new to the world of writing, and was initially surprised to read on some publishing advice website (eek) that authors should use social media to interact with readers and promote their books. How does this really play out in practice? Do publishers see more potential in you if you maintain a blog or have an active online presence? Is this essential for success?

Answer (score 2):

It varies. Some publishers really require you to be "social". Some don't.

But having social presence helps. It attracts a specific audience that may or may not be reachable through traditional means. It also garners feedback that usually is absent in traditional one-way communication.

But for certain categories, not being "social" kills sales. It doesn't take too much energy and time to be "social" unless you have thousands of views and if you reach those numbers - you could probably contract someone to handle the social presence.

I suggest that writers create a Facebook page (or a Linked In article, depending on the published material), and share it with friends and family. If you have an accessible marketing team with a publisher, they might share some of the book's graphics to be used on the Facebook page (else get ahold of some local graphics designer). Either build a story line in the posts or parallel-plot. Engage the visitors with comments or online events.

It takes a bit of time. Alternately, outsourcing it to a local social media expert saves time. (P.S. Facebook is just an example here.)

Comment: Do you think you could expand on exactly *how* writers are expected to use social media?

Comment: Create Facebook page (or linked in article depending on published material). Share it with F&F. If you have an accessible marketing team with publisher, they might share some book's graphics to be used in the Facebook page (else get hold of some local graphics designer). Either build a story line in the posts or parallel-plot. Engage the visitors with comments or online events. It takes a bit of time. Alternately, outsourcing it to a local social media expert saves time. [P.s. facebook is just an example here]

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that it's in your best interests to be social. If you're writing for a niche, then find where this niche hang out and observe. If the opportunity arises (or you can encourage it to), hold a Q&A session. Any fan likes a little attention.

Failing that, use Twitter to monitor people discussing you or your work. Get involved in conversations. Don't argue, be decent and take feedback on the chin.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Social media is a powerful weapon when yielded correctly. From monitoring trends to creating a network of potential readers, it is truly a necessary evil.

Introverts and creatives may find it difficult or nonsensical to utilize social media. It is my belief that it should be utilized whether or not your publisher requires or recommends.

Comment: Welcome to Writers! Stack Exchange Q&A sites like this one work a little differently from discussion forums; answers need to directly address the question asked. Can you expand on *how* writers are expected to use social media?